# How to decide and calculate the skewness of an asymmetric confidence interval around a mean or a mean difference?

Tags: confidence-interval, skewness

I wonder how statistical programs decide to skew the confidence interval? (I mean the confidence intervals for the means, or for the mean differences).

How do they decide on the extent of this (without any bootsrapping)? I know they do it based on the skewness of the sample distribution (in two-tailed tests), but would appreciate any details on that.

Comment: Can you give an example of what kind of interval you mean?

Comment: A simple 95% confidence interval, computed by the software for the mean errors after calculating a paired t-test. So the mean error means the mean of all X1 values - all X2 values.

Comment: A confidence interval based on a paired t-test should be symmetric. Can you show an example of an asymmetric interval for that case? When you say "the software", do you mean some software in particular?

Comment: I am looking at a paper full of asymmetric CIs for paired t-test... I don't know the software used (none mentioned), and I don't have their raw data. All I know is that most of their CIs are ridiculous compared to my CIs calculated from their mean errors and SDs.

Comment: Which paper? It's possible you've missed some detail that changes things (e.g. a transformation). It's very difficult to make sensible comments with no context.

Comment: Let me keep that paper confidential, or if you want me to send it to you, please give me an email address. I don't think they have transformed the data. But from what I have read carefully in their paper, I can say nothing is missed by me.

Comment: [none available for me]

Comment: I saw and saved your email address dear Glean. I will send the article shortly. :-)

Comment: Still haven't seen a paper.

Comment: I sent it about a week ago.